# How do I separate my dataset into train and test set by using k-fold validation?

Tags: cross-validation

I having a dataset ready for speech recognition. 
I having 10 different speakers, each utterance English digit 0 to 9 with 5 samples of each digit.

So how do I validate my dataset by using k-fold cross validation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your sample space includes only 50 samples (5 per digit) then your dataset is too small , you need to get more data (or generate through data augmentation , even if its 500 - 5 per user per digit you'll need more data to get better accuracies but you can start experimenting !!  ).

More on the sizes of datasets on [this discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51490/how-large-a-training-set-is-needed).Regarding k-fold cross validation you can follow [this documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html) if you use python.

Comment: Can I augmented my samples with different SNR value to expand my samples? for example: -10dB, -5dB, 0dB, 5dB, 10dB, 15dB and 20dB ?

Comment: I think that this is done mostly if you want to make your models more robust to noise ... that being said i think varying SNR wouldnt help you since without sufficient data it would not be able to become invariant to different types of utterances of the same word , this also depends on what model you are using..(It wouldnt hurt to try this though). There are other ways to augment dataset look at this [link] http://speak.clsp.jhu.edu/uploads/publications/papers/1050_pdf.pdf  eg changing the tempo . Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks !! if this answer  solved your problem please accept it .. helps with the reputation :)